# Modules available for Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are modules `media`, `winsound` or `wave` available for Python 3.7? Where can I find them?

When I load `media` module it tells me that Python is not found. It probably 
 is looking for previous versions of Python.

I would like to be able to find and load external modules to manipulate pictures and sound for Python 3.7.

Comment: Have you tried installing them for Python 3? What happened? How do you *"load `media` module"* and what specifically is the result?

Comment: Can you show the relevant source code you have tried so far, the commands you have tried (if any) to install the modules, and the resulting error messages? Also, your operating system and its version?

Comment: "_When I load media module it tells me that Python is not found._" - how is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install the modules.

For `media` try:

`pip3 install pygraphics`

And then in a python shell
`from pygraphics import media`

Similarly for the others this should work:

`pip3 install winsound`
`pip3 install wave`

If you don't have pip, look up directions on how to install it for your OS.